# Novice question about parsing JSON regarding uniqueness of property names when including user-provided text

Tags: javascript, json

This is likely a very stupid question, but I need to parse JSON strings in C passed from a web extension using the native-messaging API. I control the structure of the objects in JS that are passed, but some of them include user-provided content as values from textarea elements or content editable divisions.

Is it accurate that, no matter what a user types into a textarea or content editable division, it can never include a match to a true JSON property name, because every double quote will be escaped?

For example, if object is `{ ".... { "property_name" : textarea.value ... } ... }` and `property_name` isn't used as a property name at any other level within the object, it will always be unique within the JSON string itself such that searching the string in C for "property_name" (including both double quotes) will always suffice?

I found that it can appear in an array such as `[ "property_name" ]` but the user cannot type a real array or object in a textarea or content editable division.

Since everything except user-provided text content is known in advance, I don't need a generic JSON parser in C, but only that which is necessary for the specific structures used.

Thank you.

---

Thank you for the responses. I should've provide more context perhaps. All of this takes place on the client. It's in a web extension that requires a C utility, communicated with through the native-messaging API. JSON strings are constructed and parsed on both sides, but, in the C utility, they are never fully parsed. Only a few top-level properties are parsed and their values, which are more complex JSON strings, are stored as text in SQLite; so, I don't want to parse them.

Is there a JSON parser for C that can parse by level, leaving some objects
"unparsed" as strings? Do you recommend a good parser for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: *Since everything except user-provided text content is known in advance, I don't need a generic JSON parser in C* Well, that's what you should use.

Comment: Gary, for me it is not clear if you are **creating** a JSON description of something or you are **parsing** a JSON description.  Both problems are different.  Please, edit your question to clarify what you pretend (and show some code, if possible, as the question is not clear if it is related to C language, or Javascript).  BTW a JSON parser (complete) will facilitate you a lot the job.  You need a JSON parser.

Comment: @LuisColorado I removed the C tag and reference to C in the subject title. I likely shouldn't have referenced C in those places. The first line reads ` I need to parse JSON strings in C`. I need to parse JSON. I build the objects in JS and need to parse them in C.  I can parse the strings but my question is whether or not it can be relied upon that user content from a textarea or content editable division could never ever exactly match a "property_name" because the double quotes will always be escaped when coming from user input in one of those two HTML elements.

Comment: "*searching the string in C for "property_name" (including both double quotes) will always suffice?*" - no. Please use a proper JSON parser. Especially if this is a web-facing service, where you will always have to assume malicious input - not in your textarea, but directly in your API call.

Comment: @Bergi Would you please elaborate on what you mean by malicious input directly in the API call? Thank you.

Comment: @LuisColorado I just read over my response to your comment and would like to apologize because the tone may have come across as unfriendly.  It's no excuse but it was around 3:30 AM here when I wrote it and I may have been a bit on the grouchy side. There was no need for me to point out what appears in the first line. Please accept my apology and I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: @Gary Oh wait you wrote "*passed from a web extension using the native-messaging API*", no web server involved, right? Still I would recommend a proper parser, it is critical for security and correctness. Even if you can think of all edge cases, it's just not worth the effort.

Comment: @Bergi That is correct. I was just adding that as further context to my question when your last comment arrived. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need a C utility to do that at all? I would've though that web extensions have direct access to a sqlite database already.

Comment: @Bergi There is indexedDB but it is not a relational database, has a 2GB size limit, and cannot be backed up to disk unless the entire contents are first written to RAM as a giant BLOB. The C utility does more than just provide a means of data storage but, in that regard, SQLite offers a lot more than indexedDB does.